# Spring Session store user credential only

Tags: spring-mvc, session, redis, spring-data-neo4j-4, spring-session

I am currently Spring MVC 4 with Spring Data Neo4j/MongoDB/JPA. Everything works find until I need to use Spring Session Data Redis to share sessions between servers. The problem is that Spring Session intercept all the HttpSession and store them in Redis. Thus the following exception is seen:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:778)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:670)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:90)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63)
    ... 33 more
```

from which I think the `Neo4jSession` is not serializable. Thus, how can I configure Spring Session to only store client session in Redis and locally for sessions of Spring Data.

some codes:

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Config.class

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory connection = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        connection.setHostName("myhost.aliyuncs.com");
        connection.setPassword("xxxx");
        connection.setPort(6379);
        return connection; 
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem temporarily solved. I change scope of the Neo4jSession to `request`, so that it doesn't store with the session.